# PHP Startup: Can't load module 'ext\php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' - xampp

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, xampp, sqlsrv

I have problem with connectting my laravel project to SQL server database. I'am using xampp with **PHP Version 8.1.1.**
I downloaded appropriate extensions for my php version and pasted them to C:\xampp\php\ext.

**php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll 

php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll**

excerpt from php.ini file (C:\xampp\php\php.ini):

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

When trying to connect I get errors:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' as it's  linked with 14.29,
> but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Can't load module
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' as it's linked  with 14.29,
> but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:
> PHP Startup: Can't load module
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' as  it's linked with
> 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Can't load module
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' as it's  linked with
> 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0

and

> Whoops\Exception\ErrorException
>
> PHP Startup: Can't load module
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' as it's linked   with
> 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16
>
> 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\YI\vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php:486
> Whoops\Run::handleError("PHP Startup: Can't load module
> 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts.dll' as it's linked with 14.29,
> but the core is linked   with 14.16", "Unknown")
>
> 2   [internal]:0   Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a PHP error message, not an sqlsrv error message. It seems to indicate that sqlsrv and PHP have to be linked with same (or at least compatible) versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/v5.10.0/Windows-8.1.zip is what you need.

you can extract files into your ext/ directory "C:\xampp\php\ext".